# How to install Okular 20.12.0 on ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: 20.10, okular

I am using Okular from many time and I am running it in Ubuntu 20.10. I have tried it to update from 20.08.2 to 20.12.0 but it's showing Okular is upgraded to its latest version. How can I install the latest version or if I cannot install that then what is the latest Okular version for Ubuntu 20.10 ? And if anyone has the Okular 20.12.0 then kindly share the screenshot of the interface.

Comment: What feature do you need in the newer version that isn't available on the current version?  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Comment: The main thing is the interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the latest okular version using flatpak. If you don't have installed flatpak, you can do so running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
sudo apt update
sudo apt install flatpak
```

Then to enable installing from flathub, run:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Now you can install okular (the latest version):

```
flatpak install flathub org.kde.okular
```

Enjoy it!

Comment: It worked for me as follows, without having to add a ppa:
`sudo apt install flatpak` `flatpak install flathub org.kde.okular` `flatpak run org.kde.okular`
`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the safest & most stable version of any app (and Okular) is to install ONLY from snap-store (software) repositories where the latest & stable versions are kept.

Terminal command notwithstanding - snap-store is GUI-based repository which for novice users is the safest & simplest method to install/update your system.

On the "Menu", Search for “snap store” or “software”. After opening, it is pretty much self-explanatory.

The latest version of Okular. Right now it shows is 20.04.0 (updated on 03 January 2021)